# Can I open a second Gmail account in a separate app?

Tags: gmail, email, accounts

I currently have several Gmail accounts, one for work, and the others personal. I'd like to keep these separate so I can forget about work on the weekends, but I'm finding it hard to do right now.

Is there a way to open the work account in a different app (E.G., Outlook) but not have it show up in the regular Gmail client as well?

Comment: Try K-9 Mail. .

Comment: If your company uses Google Enterprise and your Android supports [work profile](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6191949), then you can have separate them for personal and work purpose.

Comment: Google Mail supports the [IMAP protocol](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en). Using this protocol you can use any regular mail app you want.

Comment: I know I can access the mail via any app, but the problem is that the Gmail app keeps fetching that mail too.

Comment: @RodeoClown with the open source email client I mentioned you don't need to add Google account to device.

Comment: Thanks @irfan latif. That might be an option. The only issue is that I actually want the account for the calendar, I just want the email left out of Gmail.

Comment: @RodeoClown there are 2 Google accounts in same user profile. Calendar app should have access to both accounts. Gmail app should have access to one account. Any other app(s) which should or shouldn't have access to one or both accounts? Please edit your question to add these details.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the answer is that it will depend...

It will depend how your work email is setup and/or the device being used.

**Option1 - Android Enterprise**
If your organization has an MDM (mobile device management) and they support a configuration called Android Enterprise it is possible they can distribute another instant if Gmail that keeps your work and personal email separate.  You will need to contact your companies help desk for more info.  Note your device must be new enough to support Android Enterprise.

**Option2 - Samsung Devices**
Some newer Samsung devices allow you to do this with a feature called Secure folder.  Secure folder allows you to add applications like gmail to the secure folder.  This allows you to run another instance of gmail or most other android.

Hope that helps